# Can I apply Edit / Edit Colors / Recolor to specific layers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector

I'm working on a many-layered file (a vector of hundreds and hundreds of people), and I'd like to make some of them, but not all of them, non-Caucasian.

Each person is their own layer in the file.

I'm trying to change some people by locking specific layers, then running Edit / Edit Colors / Recolor. But the recolor command seems to ignore the layer locks, and recolours the whole file regardless of the locked layers.

Is there any way to force Recolor to "respect" the layer locks, or any other effective way to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried *selecting* the object/layers you want changed? This should be more reliable than locking layers.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Layer select greys out the "Recolor Artwork" option so it's not even an action I can attempt.

Comment: You must select the objects not the layers.

Comment: *How* are you selecting layers? Are you merely highlighting them in the Layers panel or are you clicking the little circle to the right of their name?

Comment: That was the problem, Scott -- I was highlighting but not clicking the circles. Clicking the circles did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After locking the specific layers:

- Double click the **Magic Wand Tool**, check **Fill Color** and set a tolerance number (12)
- Click the skin color of a person
- From the **Color Panel**, choose the HSB slider and change the color

[image]